# Get the difference between 2 arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 search queries - one will display the contents for the last 7 days. The other will display the contents from 2 weeks prior. 
Both work just fine. However I want to take the results from the first query and get the difference from the second query. Then display the first query with the difference.

```
$result_account = $db->query("
SELECT nid
     , COUNT(cat) AS qty
     , dte
     , descript
     , cat
     , name
     , user 
  FROM client_note AS cn 
  JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti 
    ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid 
  JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt 
    ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id 
 WHERE dte >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
   AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' 
 GROUP 
    BY cat 
 ORDER 
    BY qty DESC 
 LIMIT 5
");
       if($count_account = $result_account->num_rows) {
               while($row = $result_account->fetch_object()){

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><h6>".$row->cat."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$row->qty."</h3></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }
       }

$result_previous = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE (dte BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
    if($count_previous = $result_previous->num_rows) {
            while($row_p = $result_previous->fetch_object()){

          echo "<tr>";  
          echo "<td><h6>".$row_p->cat."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$row_p->qty."</h3></td>";
          echo "</tr>";


            }
    }
```

First query will result in :

```
Category   - Qty
Baseball   - 45
Football   - 33
Soccer     - 21
Hockey     - 7
Basketball - 3
```

The second query will result in :

```
Category   - Qty
Basketball - 38
Soccer     - 28
Hockey     - 16
Football   - 12
Baseball   - 12
```

Now I want to display it like this

```
Category   - Qty Difference
Baseball   - 45  +33
Football   - 33  +21
Soccer     - 21  -7
Hockey     - 7   -9
Basketball - 3   -35
```

Comment: in the event that there is a "sport" that is present in one query but not in the other, do you want it omitted from the result, or assumed to be a zero and calculated accordingly?

Comment: Both queries will have all the categories - however I am only displaying the top 5.

Comment: Select a.*, a.something - b.something from(first query) a left join (second query) b on some b criteria equals some a criteria

Comment: and what happens if the "top 5 sports" from one week aren't the same as the "top 5" from the next week?  The math might get a bit weird to look at if it starts comparing numbers that do technically exist, but weren't shown on one list or the other

Comment: @adiquet you said you only display the top 5. What does top 5 mean? Top 5 from first query? Top 5 from second query? Top 5 from the difference? I can update my answer based on your reply to my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create another array that holds the values from the first query on a key->value basis and on the next one just substract the value from the respective entry in the array.

I think that this is the easiest and quickest way of doing it by using 2 queries.

Note: I did not test this code.

Note2: I assumed that a missing sport in the first category will count as a 0

Note3: the code I wrote is only to display a way of calculating the difference. Let me know if I should update it to givee the exact same output you require there.

```
$results = array();

$result_account = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE `dte` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
   if($count_account = $result_account->num_rows) {
      while($row = $result_account->fetch_object()){

        //output this query results here
        $results[$row->cat] = $row->qty;
      }
   }

$result_previous = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE (dte BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
if($count_previous = $result_previous->num_rows) {
    while($row_p = $result_previous->fetch_object()){

      //output this query results here
      $results[$row_p->cat] = ((isset($results[$row_p->cat])) ? $results[$row_p->cat] : 0 ) - $row_p->qty;
    }
}


foreach( $results as $key => $result) {
  echo "<tr>";  
  echo "<td><h6>".$key."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$result."</h3></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

UPDATE - displaying first week and difference next to it

You can try this. I got rid of the foreach and did it all using only the query loops.

NOTE: again, this is untested code

```
$results = array();

$result_account = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE `dte` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");

$result_previous = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE (dte BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC");
if($count_previous = $result_previous->num_rows) {
    while($row_p = $result_previous->fetch_object()){

      //output this query results here
      $results[$row_p->cat] = $row_p->qty;
    }
}

if($count_account = $result_account->num_rows) {
    while($row = $result_account->fetch_object()){

        $difference = $row->qty - ((isset($results[$row->cat])) ? $results[$row->cat] : 0 );

        echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td><h6>".$row->cat."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$row->qty."</h3></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$difference."</h3></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way ends up with a php error on my end that says Trying to get property 'cat' of non-object  on line 15  probably because it is not nested.. and can't find the variable.

Comment: This works -- however how would I show the current week, query 1, and then the difference next to it

Comment: Undefined variable: row  on line 13 = the while loop only references row_p. I updated it $results[$row_p->cat] = $row_p->qty; and that seems to work .. I will put it in my code and test it

Comment: Updated it. Sorry :)

Comment: So it mostly works -- I have 12 categories - if the category is in the top 5 every week it will find the right category and display the right numbers. However if one of the categories are not in the top 5 this week but was last week. That category number is off.

So If I remove the Order by qty -- and they all display as a DESC it works perfectly

Comment: That is why I asked a question on the original question: "you said you only display the top 5. What does top 5 mean? Top 5 from first query? Top 5 from second query? Top 5 from the difference? I can update my answer based on your reply to my question here."

Comment: @adiquet check it now. I removed the `limit 5` on the second query so that it pulls everything from the previous week and then in the while loop that actually displays it will pull the values it needs and calculate from there.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for this I will study this for future reference. Also yes Top 5 was the five categories with the most hits.

Comment: Awesome! glad I was able to help you! You should also review GMBs answer for a mysql way of doing the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the same data over a different period of time could be also achieved in a single SQL query, using conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT 
    cat, 
    SUM(IF(dte >= d.start1, 1, 0)) AS qty, 
    SUM(IF(dte >= d.start1, 1, 0)) - SUM(IF(dte < d.end2, 1, 0)) AS Difference, 
FROM 
    (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) start1, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) end2) as d
    CROSS JOIN client_note AS cn 
    JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid 
    JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id 
WHERE
    dte >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) 
    AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' 
GROUP BY cat 
ORDER BY qty DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Notes :

- The first subquery is just a shortcut to avoid typing the same `DATE_SUB...` expressions over and over
- I removed columns that are not used in the output
- You would need to properly alias the columns in the query ; as it is, it is hard to tell which column belongs to which table
- It is recommended (and mandatory in non-ancient MySQL versions) to put *all* non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause
- No sample data provided => not possible to test the query

PS : As commented by cornel.raiu, this approach only makes sense if you do *not* need to output the results separatly before combining them (else, you would end up running 3 SQL queries, which might not be optimal).

Comment: This is a nice one. The only thing I see is that he might want to output the results from the different queries separately as well. That is why I did not merge it in one query in my answer.

Comment: @cornel.raiu : yes you are right, I updated my answer to mention that explictly.

Comment: Thanks for this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Store the first set of numbers in two associative arrays, then in the second loop calculate the differences

```
$initial = [];
$diff = [];
$result_account = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE `dte` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
   if($count_account = $result_account->num_rows) {
           while($row = $result_account->fetch_object()){

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><h6>".$row->cat."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$row->qty."</h3></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $initial[$row->cat] = $row->qty; //remember 1st results
      $diff[$row->cat] = $row->qty; //to be used
      }
   }

$result_previous = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE (dte BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
if($count_previous = $result_previous->num_rows) {
        while($row_p = $result_previous->fetch_object()){

      echo "<tr>";  
      echo "<td><h6>".$row_p->cat."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$row_p->qty."</h3></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $diff[$row_p->cat] -= $row_p->qty; 

        }
}
//now print the initial qty and the difference
$cats = array_keys($diff);
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($cats); $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h6>".$cats[$i]."</h6></td>";
    $first = $initial[$cats[$i]];
    echo "<td><h3 class='text-primary'>$first</h3></td>"
    $d = $diff[$cats[$i]];
    $sign = $d < 0 ? "-" : "+";
    echo "<td><h3 class='text-primary'>$sign $d</h3></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

Comment: This will return an "Trying to get property 'cat' of non-object" on the second query while loop here: `$diff[$row->cat] -= $row->qty; `.

In the second query loop you don't have a `$row` but a `$row_p`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$result_account = $db->query("
SELECT nid
     , COUNT(cat) AS qty
     , dte
     , descript
     , cat
     , name
     , user 
  FROM client_note AS cn 
  JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti 
    ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid 
  JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt 
    ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id 
 WHERE dte >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
   AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' 
 GROUP 
    BY cat 
 ORDER 
    BY qty DESC 
 LIMIT 5
");

if($count_account = $result_account->num_rows) {
    while($row = $result_account->fetch_object()){
        $$key[$row->cat]= $row->qty;
    }
}

$result_previous = $db->query("SELECT nid, COUNT(cat) AS qty, dte, descript, cat, name, user FROM client_note AS cn JOIN client_note_tag_items AS cnti ON cnti.note_id = cn.nid JOIN client_note_tags AS cnt ON cnt.tag_id = cnti.tag_id WHERE (dte BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) AND name NOT LIKE 'Resolution%' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5");
if($count_previous = $result_previous->num_rows) {
    while($row_p = $result_previous->fetch_object()){
        $second_array[$row_p->cat]= $row_p->qty;
    }
}

foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
    $difference_array[$key]=$value - $second_array[$key];
}

foreach ($difference_array as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h6>".$key."</h6></td><td><h3 class='text-primary'>".$value."</h3></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I think you have too many iterations over the same thing here. You can merge the last 2 foreach loops in only 1 and do the diff just before outputting the result.

Comment: Yes you do have right i did not try to optimize but just give a hint